# Outlook calendar meeting request not working in windows 10

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hi i want to send calendar meeting event using php. Which is working all Os except windows 10.Windows 10 shows the following output
[image]

but i expect below message

[image]

Here is my code

```
 public function Getmail($id) {

 //set php variables here          


//PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->Username = "****@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "pass$";
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
        $mail->SetFrom("user@compnymail.com", "user");
        $mail->AddReplyTo("user@compnymail.com", "user");
       $mail->addAddress("user1@compnymail.com", "user1");
       mail->ContentType = 'text/calendar';

$mail->addCustomHeader('X-Mailer',"Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0");
$mail->addCustomHeader("Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");

$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$ical .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$ical .= "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN\r\n";
$ical .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= "ORGANIZER;CN=".$organizerName.":mailto:".$organizerEmail."\r\n";
$ical .= "ATTENDEE;CN=".$attendeeName.";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:".$attendeeEmail."\r\n";
$ical .= "UID:".$meeting_id."-google.com\r\n";
$ical .= "SEQUENCE:".$sequence."\r\n";
$ical .= "STATUS:".$status."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTART:".$startTime."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTEND:".$endTime."\r\n";
$ical .= "LOCATION:".$location."\r\n";
$ical .= "SUMMARY:".$summary."\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:".$description."\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
$ical .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";

$mail->Body = $ical;

//send the message, check for errors
if(!$mail->send()) {
$this->error = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
return false;
} else {
$this->error = "Message sent!";
return true;
}
```

Code is working well except windows 10.Please help me.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like the language encoding is not what window is expecting?

Comment: Have you tried using PHPMailer’s built-in iCal support?